# What does the expression "pissing on ice" mean?

Tags: meaning

In the film "Chinatown" Jake Gittes uses the expression "We'll be pissing on ice". What does it mean?

Answer (score 4):

I found this explanation from [TheFreeDictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/affluence) (near the bottom of the page):

> **piss on ice** To live luxuriously; to live high off the hog; to be wealthy, successful, or lucky. It was once the custom in posh restaurants to place a cake of ice in the urinals of men’s rooms. Thus, this expression implies that the only men who urinated on ice were those wealthy enough to patronize these exclusive and expensive dining establishments.

It also seems to be corroborated by [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pissing%20on%20ice):

> To be financially well to do, or generally fortunate.
>
> term from the early 1900's where public places would have troughs to piss in and the piss would just run out, no runnning water or anything. The high price places would put ice in the trough so you piss would melt the ice and drain, producing less smell. therfore if you were rich you were "pissing on ice".

Comment: So, flushed with success?

Comment: Urban Dictionary is of no real value even for corroboration.

Comment: Urban Dictionary is like evidence obtained from an illegal source: it can put the investigator onto the right track but can't be used as evidence in court.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Urban Dictionary, *pissing on ice* means:

> To be financially well to do, or generally fortunate.
>
> term from the early 1900's where public places would have troughs to piss in and the piss would just run out, no runnning water or anything. The high price places would put ice in the trough so you piss would melt the ice and drain, producing less smell. therfore if you were rich you were "pissing on ice".
>   Steve: I just won $500 in a poker game
>
> Paul: you a lucky son of a bitch.
>
> Steve: yea i'm pissing on ice today man.